# Trying to read numpy array into opencv - cv2.imdecode returns empty argument

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, matplotlib, fits

Just getting back into coding after a few years out. Trying to write a piece of code that can go through a folder with .fits files, read out the image data, convert them to an array, read them into opencv, then perform edge detection on them. I can get it working fine with .png files as I don't have to play with arrays. I've done a lot of reading about, and that's enabled me to get to this point. Problem is, img is currently being returned empty, which causes everything else to freak. Any ideas please? Any help would be gratefully received!

```
#import packages

import cv2
from matplotlim import pyplot as plt
import os
from astropy.io import fits
from skimage import img_as_uint
import numpy as np

#create array with filenames

data = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'/Users/hannah/Desktop/firefountain-testset'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.fits'):
            data.append(file)

#start my loop through the folder
for i in data:
    fn = i
#read fits image data
    hdulist = fits.open(fn)
    img_data = hdulist[1].data
#put fits data into array with dtype set as original
    imgraw=np.array(img_data, dtype = np.uint8)
#convert to uint16 
    img = img_as_uint(imgraw)
#crop to area of interest then add into array - possibly don't need second line
    imgcrop = img[210:255,227:277]
    imgcroparr = np.array(imgcrop)
#attempt to read into cv2 - this is where it loses the data 
#all fine before this point I believe
    imgfinal = cv2.imdecode(imgcroparr, 0,)
    plt.imshow(imgfinal) 
#imgfinal returns blank.
```

[google drive with .fits files I'm using, plus .png to show what they should look like](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5sX66D_9xkwb18tdGpwU1M3bTA)

## Updated my code

```
for i in data:
    fn = i
    imgraw = fits.getdata(fn)
    imgcrop = imgraw[210:255,227:277]
    img = cv2.imdecode(imgcrop, 0,)
    plt.imshow(img)
```

This opens the fits files no issue and imgcrop works as expected. cv2.imdecode(imgcrop, 0), however, throws up the following:

error: /Users/jhelmus/anaconda/conda-bld/work/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:307: error: (-215) buf.data && buf.isContinuous() in function imdecode_

Can't find anything on this error in this context online, getting more and more confused. It's probably something very silly and basic that I've forgotten to do, but I can't see it.

Comment: Can you share one of your `.fits` files? Because with a random example I found somewhere online, things already start to go crazy around `imgraw=np.array(img_data, ...)`, as `img_data` doesn't look like something that you can cast to a `numpy.array`

Comment: `#put fits data into array with dtype set as original
    imgraw=np.array(img_data, dtype = np.uint8)` What is the point of this part?  FITS data is already returned as a Numpy array.   Also make sure you have read this: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/appendix/faq.html#why-is-an-image-containing-integer-data-being-converted-unexpectedly-to-floats

Comment: @Iguananaut The point of the adding to array is to change it from 8bit to 16bit (I think that way round) - so that cv2 doesn't freak. Partly added as it was something my not-supervisor suggested I might well need to do for it to work. I don't think the issues discussed on that link are the issue - but I'm not certain. It is a helpful link though, so thank you very much!

Comment: @Bart - I've just added a link to Google drive with some files - both png and fits. I find it works until the last two lines. It could be with with position of hdulist I'm calling - as sometimes it's 0, sometimes it's 1 - depending on the file

Comment: Well that would do it.  If the files you're processing use a standard extension name for the extension that contains the data you want you can use the extension name instead of the extension name (e.g. `hdulist['SCI']` instead of `hdulist[1]`).  Alternatively you can use the `fits.getdata()` convenience function which will just return that data of the first HDU that has data.

Comment: `#put fits data into array with dtype set as original
    imgraw=np.array(img_data, dtype = np.uint8)
#convert to uint16 
    img = img_as_uint(imgraw)`  Here you're immediately making a copy of the array as bytes, and then making a copy again to convert it to whatever `img_as_uint` does.

Comment: @Iguananaut thank you! I hadn't realised there was a convenience function - I'm going to mention that to other people that use these as I don't think they'll know about it either. I've also updated the question with the error message I'm getting - I definitely think the issue is in the imdecode function somewhere, but I'm not sure where?

Comment: Please keep in mind the warning in this section when suggesting the convenience functions: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html#convenience-functions  Though I have some changes I'm hoping to get in that will make it a moot point.  For your application though, at least as written, `getdata` should be fine.

Comment: There appears to be an assertion (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp#L307) that the buffer it's being passed (in this case the numpy array) is non-empty and contiguous.  It's obviously not non-empty.  It *could* be non-contiguous though since you're taking a slice out of the larger array.  So I guess in this case you do need to copy the array after all!  (But only after slicing it.)